# ignoring replicated data from a data stream

Tags: c#

I'm having a problem with C# code. I have a data stream from a radio system. There are three fields. UserID, ClockTime, TalkGroup 
As long as the User is transmitting all three fields are streaming, the userID field I don't need to see over and over again. How can I read this and display the user only once. The clock time and the talkgroup are real time and will change.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If we could see your code that would help, however I might have a hunch that may help you! If you reading a string in you could split it into an array, depending on how you are reading the data it could be split on a whitespace or ',' or whatever's splitting your data up and then just output the user id on the first iteration (i.e if(counter < 1){Console.WriteLine(userID);})